# $A = \mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^3-1)$ is an integral closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $A = \mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^3-1)$ and $L$ be the quotient field of $A$. $x,y$ denotes the classes of $X,Y$. Prove that $L$ is a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{C}(y)$ and $A$ is the integral closure of $\mathbb{C}[y]$ in $L$.

I have no idea in the first question. In the second question I tried to prove $A$ is integrally closed because $A$ is integral over $\mathbb{C}[y]$, but in vain. How to prove ?

Comment: Can you think of a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb C(y)$ which has $x$ as a root?

Comment: Note that $A$ is regular and one-dimensional, hence normal. Thus you only have to show that its integral over $\mathbb C[y]$, which is trivial, right?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez $L=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ ,$x^2+y^3-1=0$ and $x^2+y^3-1$ is irreducible. It is right?